# A Question About the Use of "who is believed to"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have a question regarding the grammatical use of "who is believed to".

(a) The old banker, who is believed to be funding the syndicate.

(b) The old banker, who is believed to fund the syndicate.

So, I know that (a) is actually correct, my question is that can we use (b) too? Just as the way we use (a)? I mean, is it grammatically correct to use the phrase "who is believed to" that way, or is "be" mandatory there?

Thanks, and sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: Both are correct. The difference between the sentences is the tense of what is believed: a) continuous present ("he is funding...") b) simple present ("he funds"). Check the usage of each tense to see which is appropriate.

Comment: a is more idiomatic in most cases, I think.